# Stop Fragment Timer onCloseActivity

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments, timer

I have a fragment where a timer starts running immediately when you initialize and it shows a different image every 6 seconds.

I haven't fully figured out how this timer thing works, but somehow i got it running and i understand the timer runs in a different thread... not even sure what exactly that means : )

But the timer causes a crash when i load a different fragment. so i guess i have to CANCEL the timer when the activity is closed?

That brings me to two questions.
1) Can i run myTimer.cancel from anywhere? if yes, how do i run it from my main activity or from other fragments.

2) is there something like onCloseActivity i can use for this fragment. so i can cancel my timer as soon as i leave the fragment?

this is how i start my timer:

// timer
    Timer myTimer;

```
/////////////////////
/////// timer ///////
/////////////////////
private void runTimer() {

    myTimer = new Timer();
    myTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            TimerMethod();
        }

    }, 5000, 5000);
}

private Runnable Timer_Tick = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        // next image if THIS one is loaded
        nextImage();
    }
};

private void TimerMethod() {
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
}
```

And here is my error:
getActivity().runOnUiThread(Timer_Tick);
causes the error when i load a different fragment.

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Timer-1
>   Process: com.murmurcalgary.murmurcalgaryevolvd, PID: 8668
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)' on a null object reference
>   at com.murmurcalgary.murmurevolvd.fragments.EventsFragment.TimerMethod(EventsFragment.java:92)
>   at com.murmurcalgary.murmurevolvd.fragments.EventsFragment.access$000(EventsFragment.java:45)
>   at com.murmurcalgary.murmurevolvd.fragments.EventsFragment$1.run(EventsFragment.java:77)
>   at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)

Comment: "EventsFragment.java:92" What is line 92 of EventsFragment.java?

Comment: Sanjeet's answer is correct . You also can check if current Context is NULL or not before calling nextImage() method. I guess you can use if(getApplicationContext()!=null) for that purpose .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use fragment's life-cycle methods for stopping the timer.

Override onStop() method in fragment and then cancel the timer task inside that method.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if(timerTask != null){
        timerTask.cancel();
        //cancel timer task and assign null
    }
}
```